# Open Street Map enclosing polygons

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am working on an Android application that uses the Overpass API at [1]. My goal is to get all circular ways that enclose a certain lat-long point.

In order to do so I build a request for a rectangle that contains my location, then parse the response XML and run a ray-casting algorithm to filter the ways that enclose the given lat-long position. This is too slow for the purpose of my application because sometimes the response has tens or hundreds of MB.

Is there any OSM API that I can call to get all ways that enclose a certain location? Otherwise, how could I optimize the process?

Thanks!

[1] http://overpass-api.de/

Comment: Why would you want to do such a complex analysis in an Android application? Or: what do you really want to achieve in your app?

Comment: I need to show an overlay on the map with the smallest enclosing polygon that I can find whenever the user clicks a certain point on the respective map.

Comment: What kind of polygons? Buildings, Countries, …?

Comment: The ones that I need the most are buildings / parks / lakes.

Comment: @AndreiSfrent I tried to sum up my ideas in my answer below, but I would really appreciate if your could add more details about your application in further questions -- some aspects are not described in  great detail (e.g. do your *have* to use Overpass or is it just a solution to the data acquiration problem?), so I can't really tell of how much value my suggestions are to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no standard API in OSM to do this (it is indeed a very uncommon usecase).

I assume you define *enclose* as *the point representing the current location is inside the inner area of the polygon*. Furthermore I assume *optimizing the process* might including changing the entire concept of the algorithm.

First of all, you need to define the rectangle to fetch data. For that, you need to consider that querying a too large rectangle would yield too much data. As far as I know there is no specific API to query circular ways only, and even if there is, querying a too large rectangle would probably denied by the server, because the server load would be enormous.

### Server-side precomputation / prefiltering

Therefore I suggest the first optimization: Instead of querying an API that is not specifically suited for your purpose, use an offline database saved on the Android device. *OsmAnd* and others save the whole database for a country offline, but in your specific usecase you only need to save a  pre-filtered database of circular ways.

As far as I know, only a small fraction of the ways in OSM is circular. Therefore I suggest writing a script that regularly downloads OSM dumps e.g. from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/), remove non-circular ways (e.g. you could check if the last node ID in a way is equal to the first node ID, but you'd need to check if that captures any way you would define as circular). How often you would run it depends on your usecase.

This optimization solves:

- The issue of downloading a large amount of data
- The issue of overloading the API with large request
- The issue of not being able to request large chunks of data

If that is not suitable for your usecase, I suggest to build a simple API for that on your server.

### Re-chunking the data into appriopriate grids

However, you still would need to filter a large amount of data. In order to partially solve this, I suggest the second optimization: Re-chunk your data. For example, if your current location is in Virginia, you would not need to filter circular ways that have an area not beyond Texas. Because filtering by state etc. would by highly country-dependent and difficult (CPU-intensive), I suggest to choose a grid, say e.g. 0.05 lat/lon degree (I'd choose a equirectangular projection because it's easy to calculate if you already have lat/lon coordinates).

The script that preprocessed that data shall then create one chunk of data (that could be a file, but we don't know enough about your usecase to talk about specific data strucutres) for any rectangle in the area you want to use. A circular way is included in this chunk if and only if it has at least one node that is inside the chunk area.

You would then only request / filter the specific chunk your position is currently in. Choose the chunk size appropriately for your application (preferably rather small, but that depends on numerous factors!).

This optimization solves:

- Assuming most of the circular ways are quite small in terms of their bounding rectangles, you only need to filter a tiny fraction of the overall ways
- IO is minimized, especially if you

### Hysteretic heuristics

If the aforementioned optimizations do not sufficiently reduce your computation time, I'd suggest the third optimization that depends on *how many* circular ways you want to find (if you really need to find *all*, it won't help at all): Use hysteresis. Save the circular ways you were inside of during the last computation (assuming the new current location is near to the last location) and check them first. If your location didn't change too much, you have a high chance of hitting a way you're inside of during the first few raycasts.

### Leveraging relations between different circular ways

Also, a fourth optimization is possible: There will be some circular ways that are fully enclosed in another circular way. You could code your program so that it knows about that relation and checks the inner circular way first. If this check succeeds, you automatically now that the current position is also contained in the outer circular way. I think computing the information (server-side) could be incredibly CPU-intensive and implementing it might also be a hard task, so I'd suggest to use this optimization only if not avoidable.

Tuning the parameters of these optimizations should be sufficient to decrease the CPU time needed for your computation significantly. Please feel free to comment/ask if you have further questions regarding these suggestions.